# c# write to text file on website trough php

Tags: c#, php, text-files

Within c#, i can put data to seperate strings.
For example the current date i put to a string called line1 and some info i put to a string called line2.

What i want to do now, is sent these 2 strings to a web adress that handles these lines, and write them into a simple text file. (or can i write to a text file on a website directly from C# ?)

My knowlage of php is very low, but so far i found this code to be working:

```
<?php 
 $File = "name.txt"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
 $Data = "line1\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 $Data = "line2\n"; 
 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 print "Data Added"; 
 fclose($Handle); 
 ?>
```

The C# application is running on a computer, not the website (WPF window).
But now it only has the content of the $Data written to the "name.txt"  file. 
Does anyone know how i could link the text that is binded to the stings in C3, to the datafields defined in the PHP, so that the text from the strings gets written to the text file on the website? Or would it be possible to write directly to a text file without the php in between ?

Comment: What do you mean "i want to be written to the text file on the website"?

Comment: i guess that is my great english not explaining well :-P. But what i ment is, how i can paste the text that is binded to my string in c#, to one of the data fields in php, that gets written to the text file on the website.

Comment: Does the C#-App also run on the server?

Comment: No, the C# is just on the computer. Dont know if it matters, it is a WPF app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a C# app that you want to use to send 2 bits of data to a PHP based website, and have the website write the data into a file?  If that's what you want, you'll need to do something like the following...

On the website, create a receiving PHP file.  The bones of it would be something like :

```
<?php 
$File = "name.txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
$line1 = $_GET["line1"] . "\n"; 
fwrite($Handle, $line1); 
$line2 = $_GET["line2"]; 
fwrite($Handle, $line2); 
print "Data Added"; 
fclose($Handle); 
echo "Completed writing data to the file";
?>
```

and to submit that data from the C# app to the website, do something as simple as

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/Receiver.php?line1=this is the first line&line2=and this is the second"));
```

(
NOTE : No error handling is included in this code, and anyone who knows the URL for the receiver will be able to overwrite your file with whatever they like.  Take care when actually implementing this.
ALSO NOTE : It is years since I did much with PHP, so you will probably need to tweak the code.
AND ANOTHER THING : the WebClient.DownloadString approach is as basic as it gets.  You may want to look at HttpWebRequests if you need more control
)

Comment: This is exactly working as i wanted. Thank you very much. I am aware of the risks having it so open, but that does not matter for now, its for testing purposes. The error handling at the C# i can handle (i guess), but i dont have much knowlage of php, so for now i leave it as your example. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a text file on a website directly from C#.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("/file.txt"););
file.WriteLine("First line.");
file.WriteLine("Secondline.");
file.Close();
```

It will create a file in the root of your website (the user running the site has to have write permissions in this directory)

Comment: ahaa, and i guess i get change the path easy to direct it to some sub dir on the website ? for example the root/public_html/textfile/file.txt  (btw, your code seems to give some errors?)

Comment: Yes, you can change the path like this. I can see there is one semicolon  to much (after mappath). I did not compile it, so it's possible there is something else. But the idea is good.

Comment: strange enough, the `Server.MapPath` gives me a error in C# 2010 express. it seems it does not know the `MapPath` part. even if i make it `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.MapPath`, it gives an error that there is no such namespace in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Server :/

Comment: Wrong namespace. It should be: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(PATH)

Comment: hehehe, "the type or namespace name "HttpContext" does not exist in the namespace "System.Web" (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: This answer assumes C# code running on the server in ASP.NET, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Okay, the questions was not clear. Now I see that there is a lack of some basic knowledge. @Dante1986: I do not know what you are exactly doing, but there is a way to find the path and it cannot be to difficult to google it. Then you can use my code to write to a file. Cheers.